# What is your preferred WordPress theme framework?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

First of all I must say I am more a programmer than a designer, so my knowledge and capability for designing a "fancy" interface is not on par with a normal web designer.

I often come in situations like customers want me to finish their blog - or mini CMS ASAP. And their first preference would usually be WordPress. No offense, but I feel it is a bit hard for me to quickly craft a theme to exactly suit their demand.

I know I can purchase or just grab some themes from online but that would not always do.

Now that there are a couple of WordPress theme FRAMEWORKS out there, accroding to [this official link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Frameworks), I wonder if any of you have experienced with any of those, and what do you feel about it?

Personally I just downloaded and tried one of them, which is called [Thematic](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/thematic). Spent one night struggled to customize but unfortunately I was sort of lost in the maze of files...

Maybe I should have consulted to some books about WordPress theme development, but if you can share your experience with me that would be most appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions with the word "favorite" and/or the phrase "how to you feel about it" in them are automatically "S&A" :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo : sorry I didn't know that. I will change the term to "preferred" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have good experience working with [Thesis](http://diythemes.com/thesis/).

Very easy to configure and has BIG A*s Save Button.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will certainly come there and give it a try!

Comment: @Yada : I already purchased the Personal edition. Thanks for your info! Hopefully this can save my a*s a lot!